# Claiming a Ticket in RT via REST

Tags: rest, rt

I'm currently working on using Javascript to make REST calls to our Request Tracker system. The Javascript hasn't been a problem so far, but the documentation for RT+REST is just a little bit sparse. The goal is to claim a ticket. I've tried sending (POST):

```
REST/1.0/ticket/$num/take
```

And I get an error about not having a required parameter 'changes'

Then, I tried this:

```
REST/1.0/ticket/$num/take

id: $num
action: take
```

And I get the same error message. The last thing I've tried was:

```
REST/1.0/ticket/742685/edit

id: $num
action: take
```

And the response was "RT/ver 200 Ok" with all of the ticket information, but it didn't actually transfer ownership.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that someone else can use this, I think most of the RT REST/v1 endpoints require that all of the "key: value" strings be wrapped under a "content" key in the request payload. I also didn't see anything about a /take endpiont, so I might try something like:

```
var endpoint = base + 'REST/1.0/ticket/742685/edit'
var payload = {'content' : "id: 742685\n Owner: Some New Owner"}
makePost(endpoint, payload)
```

Worth a shot.